# python merge two dataframe with common columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframe, which has 3 column with same name.

```
df1 = ['id','first','last','present']
df2 = ['id','first','last','age','date','location']
```

I want to join on these three common columns, I tried following

```
cols = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)
result = pd.merge(df1, df2[cols_to_use], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

to get

```
['id','first','last','present','age','date','location']
```

Is this can be done in step `pd.merge` ?

Comment: `left_on`, `right_on`

Comment: Wait, why doesn't `df1.merge(df2)` work just like that?

Comment: Specifically, `df1.merge(df2, how='outer')`

Comment: df1.merge(df2, how='outer') gives `NaN` for column in table.